# Can someone tell me why my vertex is not properly snapping to other vertex

Tags: modeling, snapping

[image]

I am trying to rig a Minecraft character and today I am trying to make sharp 90 and 127 degree bend.

I made 90 bend very easily but in 127 bend I got this problem.

Comment: Your pivot point on the right one seems to be a vert in the center

Answer (score 1):

you've enabled Snapping Accidentally. click on Magnet Icon to Disable it.
[image]

Comment: I think they want snapping, but you can see the second vert snaps to a position very far away from the mouse cursor.  I can't figure out why